# ASP.NET Application Install - Strategy needed

Tags: asp.net, sql, iis

I've built an open source ASP.NET web application and now I'm moving towards release. I'm keen to offer an easy install for my users but I'm having real problems coming up with a solution.

The app needs to have a site setup in IIS and a SQL Database installed. What is the easiest deployment process for my users you can think of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into the new Web Platform Installer.

http://www.microsoft.com/Web/downloads/platform.aspx

I haven't watched this but know Paul:

http://www.motusconnect.com/blog/2009/4/29/installing-umbraco-using-the-web-platform-installer

Answer (score 0):

You can create setup and deployment projects from within Visual Studio to aid in getting the application placed properly within IIS.  As for database setup, you might consider writing a setup form within your website that can be called once to initialize the database based on user input (think about the setup process from popular open-source projects like WordPress or phpBB that perform a wizard-type function).

Scott Guthrie also has a really cool blog post about creating deployment projects [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/06/15/tip-trick-creating-packaged-asp-net-setup-programs-with-vs-2005.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest for your users is an MSI which lets them choose any relevant options through the GUI. It also has the advantage that you'll be able to upgrade it using MSI and people who want to automate it can install it using MsiExec.

A good place to start with MSIs is [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/).